# Syntax error in very simple program

Tags: c++

I'm writing my first C++ application. But I get syntax error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int result = get_num();

    cout << "Result is " << result << endl;

    system("pause");   
    return 0;
}

int get_num(void) { 
    return 1;
}
```

And compiler said me:

> main.cpp(10): error C3861: 'get_num': identifier not found

Comment: You need to at least declare your function before you use it.

Comment: put the definition of the function above main.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

1) declare a prototype of `get_num` before `main`:

```
int get_num(void);
int main() {
}
```

2) move your definition of `get_num` before `main`.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to add a forward declaration before `main` like so:

```
int get_num(void) ;
```

the other solution would be to put the definition of `get_num` before `main` and then you would not need a forward declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Write `int get_num(void);` above the `main()` function.

C++ requires variables and functions to be declared above the current scope.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare or define the function before using it in the main.
To declare just add

```
 int get_num(void);
```

at the beginning of your code. If not define the entire function before main like so- 
Try-

```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;
    int get_num(void) { 
    return 1;
    }

    int main() {

    int result = get_num();

    cout << "Result is " << result << endl;

    system("pause");   
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you need to declare all variables/functions that you want to use before using them. You're using getnum in main but you haven't declared it in the function. Writing int get_num(); outside main will declare this at a global scope. i.e. any function in that file would be able to use it. declaring get_num(); inside a function will enable you to use this function only inside that particular function.